# find and copy files change the modified date to 1980-1-1

Tags: files, find, timestamps, cygwin

I use command to find and copy files in cygwin in windows . My command is

```
find -name '*.docx' -exec cp -p -t /word {} +
```

however , when the files is copied to destination folder, I can see the modified date is retained, but soon the file modified date is become 1-1-1980, am I using wrong syntax?

Comment: Your command is correct. Anyway, if the file date is correct immediately after the copy, that shows that it was copied correctly. This is presumably some Windows oddity, but it is strange. Are you running some kind of antivirus? Do you have this problem if you turn it off (if you can)?